# SSH connection refused and no ping reply from ubuntu server using other networks

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I recently setup Ubuntu Server 22.04 to my old PC and got it running fine, until I tried to SSH it from another location and connection refused. I then tried to ping it which didn't work either. I have made my IP static with DuckDNS, setup port forwarding on my router, allowed port 22 on firewall, removed and reinstalled OpenSSH and basically tried every trick in the book. On my local network everything works fine, it's only when I try to connect from another location when it's refused. I also have Docker installed, could it be messing with the connection?

I am completely at a loss here. What should i do to get it working?

Comment: try ``tracepath $ip_addr''

Comment: "*On my local network everything works fine, it's only when I try to connect from another location when it's refused*" Then your server is configured correctly. Stop mucking with it. Look at your DDNS and port forwarding correctly again very very carefully. In some cases, some ISPs block ssh access.